# Select distinct and add one to that value

Tags: sql

I have a database with a column containing year-week in this format "202030, 202031" and so on. However the weeks are US-format and to be in Swedish format I need to add 1 to this integer.

I have this query that works but gives me the "wrong week":
`Select distinct date_week FROM table Order by date_week desc`

I have tried this without success:
`Select distinct date_week +1 FROM table Order by date_week desc`

How do I add +1 to the volumes in that date-week column?

Comment: If it is an "integer" then `+ 1` should work in any database.

Comment: could you check the exemple of year-month field? 202030 do not exist… 202003 stay for march, 202004 for april and so on… Or the table is Year-Week? Do you have also the full date? Because the us-format means only the week starts from Sunday, +1 adjust it for this year, not forever...

Comment: "Year-Month format"  when did 30 and 31 becomes months?  I don't understand the question.  Did you mean Year-Week?  What data type is the date_week?  As always sample data and expected results help clarify a question and expectation.

Comment: I'm sorry, I mean year week, truly sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
select date_week + 1 
from table 
group by date_week
order by date_week desc;
```

You don't specify the issue with your query, but it might simply be the `select distinct`.